# How do I specify dtype with read_csv for data and index independently

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to specify the `dtype` of the values when loading a pandas dataframe, but only for the values in the dataframe, not the index. Is this possible?

```
from io import StringIO
my_csv = StringIO('''b, c\nx, 1, 2\ny, 3, 2''')
```

I would have assumed the following would work:

```
pd.read_csv(my_csv, dtype='int64')
```

But if fails with:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'
```

I can load the table without specifying `dtype` and then set it to just the values, but is there a way I can do this directly when reading the table?

Comment: docs of ```read_csv```: ```dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} (Unsupported with engine=’python’). Use str or object to preserve and not interpret dtype.```

Comment: this won't work as you've not specified which columns to use that dtype for, is this a representative example for what you're trying to do because if you didn't pass the dtype arg then it would just work?

Comment: I was hoping to have *all* of the values be loaded as ints. This seems reasonable as loading the table without specifying dtype creates a dataframe where the index and header are strings and the values are floats. I would like strings for the index and ints for the values. I need the data to be ints in order to use other packages downstream that require it.

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to read just the header to get the column names and then `zip` them with your desired dtype and read the csv again:

```
In [6]:
t="""b,c
x,1,2
y,3,2"""
cols = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), nrows=1).columns
dtyp = dict(zip(cols,['int64'] * len(cols)))
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), dtype=dtyp).info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2 entries, x to y
Data columns (total 2 columns):
b    2 non-null int64
c    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
```